# Смена картинки при клику <img 1> <img2> и так далее

Tags: javascript, карусель, слайдер

Еесть 10 картинок, они отображаются подряд списком.

```
<img src="..1" /> 
<img src="..2" />
```

Как для экономии места, описать в js чтобы отображалась одна картинка, а при клике на неё показывалась следующая, и так по кругу.

Похоже на карусель, но без авто-прокрутки.

(Плагинов куча, но я не любитель плагинов. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

много есть способов, вот например

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img')).forEach(function(el, i, arr) {
    i && (el.style.display = 'none');
    el.onclick = function(e) {
        el.style.display = 'none';
        arr[i + 1 === arr.length ? 0 : i + 1].style.display = 'inherit';
    }
});
```

но я бы на Вашем месте добавил к этим изображениям класс:

```
<img class='slider' src='...'/>
<img class='slider' src='...'/>
```

чтобы точно выбрать со страницы только их

```
document.querySelectorAll('img.slider');
```